# Could the side effect of atomic operation be seen immediately by other threads?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, concurrency, memory-barriers

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795265/will-atomic-operations-block-other-threads) one replier says

> Atomicity means that operation either executes fully **and all it's side effects are visible**, or it does not execute at all.

However, below is an example given in **Concurrency in Action $Lising 5.5**

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
std::atomic<int> x(0),y(0),z(0);
std::atomic<bool> go(false);
unsigned const loop_count=10;
struct read_values
{
  int x,y,z;
};
read_values values1[loop_count];
read_values values2[loop_count];
read_values values3[loop_count];
read_values values4[loop_count];
read_values values5[loop_count];
void increment(std::atomic<int>* var_to_inc,read_values* values)
{
  while(!go)
  std::this_thread::yield();
  for(unsigned i=0;i<loop_count;++i)
  {
    values[i].x=x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    values[i].y=y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    values[i].z=z.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    var_to_inc->store(i+1,std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::this_thread::yield();
  }
}

void read_vals(read_values* values)
{
  while(!go)
  std::this_thread::yield();
  for(unsigned i=0;i<loop_count;++i)
  {
    values[i].x=x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    values[i].y=y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    values[i].z=z.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::this_thread::yield();
  }
}
void print(read_values* v)
{
  for(unsigned i=0;i<loop_count;++i)
  {
    if(i)
    std::cout<<",";
    std::cout<<"("<<v[i].x<<","<<v[i].y<<","<<v[i].z<<")";
  }
  std::cout<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
  std::thread t1(increment,&x,values1);
  std::thread t2(increment,&y,values2);
  std::thread t3(increment,&z,values3);
  std::thread t4(read_vals,values4);
  std::thread t5(read_vals,values5);
  go=true;
  t5.join();
  t4.join();
  t3.join();
  t2.join();
  t1.join();
  print(values1);
  print(values2);
  print(values3);
  print(values4);
  print(values5);
}
```

The sample output given by author is

```
(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(2,0,0),(3,0,0),(4,0,0),(5,7,0),(6,7,8),(7,9,8),(8,9,8),(9,9,10)
(0,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,2,0),(1,3,5),(8,4,5),(8,5,5),(8,6,6),(8,7,9),(10,8,9),(10,9,10)
(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,2),(0,0,3),(0,0,4),(0,0,5),(0,0,6),(0,0,7),(0,0,8),(0,0,9)
(1,3,0),(2,3,0),(2,4,1),(3,6,4),(3,9,5),(5,10,6),(5,10,8),(5,10,10),(9,10,10),(10,10,10)
(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(0,0,0),(6,3,7),(6,5,7),(7,7,7),(7,8,7),(8,8,7),(8,8,9),(8,8,9)
```

The output seems that the modification in one thread **is not visible to other thread immediately**.

And the author also says:

> Thread 3 **doesn’t see any of the updates to x or y;** it sees only the updates it
>   makes to z. This doesn’t stop the other threads from seeing the updates to z
>   mixed in with the updates to x and y though.

I'm confused that why thread3 doesn't see the modification of `x` and `y`. Does that mean **atomic operation's side effects are visible** is not true?Does that obey the cache coherency rule, which is guaranteed by computer hardware?

Comment: The only guarantee you get is that (quote) _an implementation should make atomic stores visible to atomic loads within a reasonable amount of time_..
A read-modify-write (RMW) operation has a stronger guarantee; It will become visible 'immediately' to another RMW since they operate on the latest in the modification order.

Comment: @LWimsey If the side effects are not visible to other thread immediately, does that obey the cache coherency rule?

Comment: It does obey cache coherency, but simply means that an architecture may delay a store before it hits the (coherent) L1 cache. During that delay, other cores will not yet see it.
Also note that cache coherency is an optional feature; a platform does not have to support it.

Comment: @LWimsey What about common home used computer?  The atomic operation still could have time latency before it's visible to other thread/cpu?

Comment: The common `X86` platform may delay a store before it becomes visible to other cores. Search for 'X86 write buffer'

Comment: @LWimsey I'm not sure what you mean by "delay a store". Since the operation is atomic, which is not splittable, why is there a single store operation?